# Confused about MERGE sometimes creating duplicate relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query when a user `VISITED` another user's profile

```
    MATCH (you:User {user_id: { myId }}), (youVisited:User {user_id: { id }})
    MERGE (you)-[yvr:VISITED]->(youVisited)
    SET yvr.seen = false, yvr.created_at = timestamp()
    RETURN yvr.created_at as visited_at
```

I noticed that in rare cases, a duplicate `[:VISITED]` relationship happens. Both have the same properties, and there's really only supposed to be one `[:VISITED]` no matter what (the next time the user visits, it should simply MERGE the `[:VISITED]` and update the `[:VISITED {created_at: ..., seen: false}]` between the same User nodes:

```
{
    created_at: 1485800172734,
    seen: false
}
```

[image]

I thought the point of `MERGE` to prevent this? Clearly not, so why does this happen and how can I ensure this doesn't happen?

**UPDATE: I read the "Duplicate Question", and am still not sure what I need to do. This is duplicate relationship, not duplicate nodes. How do I create a constraint on a relationship, if that's even the solution?**

Comment: In duplicate relationship properties match or different?

Comment: Both of the (1057)-[:VISITED]->(630) relationships have the same properties. I intended for there to only be one though. I only want to create one `VISITED` relationship no matter what, and only update that the next time the user visits.

Comment: What version of Neo and how are you executing the MERGE? Seems like there was a bug in this area: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/issues/239

Comment: 3.1.0 using latest https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver.